# Opera + border-radius + svg background = bug?

Tags: xml, svg, opera

i've got bug in Opera 11.64 browser. Check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/wqCDm/13/

Button has `background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64...` and is located in block with `position: fixed`. When you start scroll page background rolls away, and after you get back to the top it shows up again.

Without `border-radius` it works properly.

Comment: could you mark it as resolved. Thanks for reporting too. I updated my answer below with the bug number, so you can track in the future in Opera releases changelog.

Answer (score 3):

I confirmed that this is a bug and it is still the case in Opera 12. Did you report it on [Opera Bugs Reporting system](https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/)?

**Update 2012-06-21**: OK. CONFIRMED. It is now CORE-47072 in Opera Internal Bug tracking system.

Comment: yep, report has been sent. Hope it will fixed soon

Comment: @user1468375 do you have the bug number so I can track it. Thanks.