# Opera: position: fixed & background-image

Tags: css, positioning, background-image, opera, css-position

On my page I have an element with the following CSS rules:

```
.pointer {
    position: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    top: 70%;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 3%;
    height: 6%;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("img/myImage.jpg");
}
```

Works good in the browsers I tested, only Opera does not like it. When I scroll, the background image also gets "scrolled" and therefore disappears as is gets out of the container.
I believe that is a known problem, but still I wasn't able to find a solution.

On [this page](http://john.albin.net/css/owen-hack) a method is described how to hide CSS rules from Opera, but besides the fact that this post is anno 2002, I actually don't want to use CSS hacks.

Removing `overflow: hidden` does not fix it, adding `background-attachment: fixed` didn't help either. Any other ideas or solutions?

**EDIT:**
http://jsfiddle.net/mvV7G/

Comment: Could you create a demo for us?  (see:  http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @cimmanon Added a Fiddle. Of course it has to be opened in opera for the bug to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken a look at your fiddle project. I believe that the problem is caused by having the background image and border radius applied to the same element, I honestly can't explain why this only happens in opera.

But a simple solution is to wrap the anchor in a div and split the styling between each, ensuring that the background image and radius are on separate elements.

I have created a fiddle with a possible solution, it needs some tidying up but I think it will get you on track - http://jsfiddle.net/zyj6Z

The CSS is below:

```
.link {
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4d000000, endColorstr=#4d000000)";
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4d000000, endColorstr=#4d000000);
zoom: 1;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxNiIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxNiI+PHBvbHlnb24gZmlsbD0iI2ZmZiIgcG9pbnRzPSIyLjc2OSw3Ljk5MiAxMC43NjIsMCAxMy4xMzIsMi4zNjIgNy42MDQsNy44OTkgMTMuMjMxLDEzLjUyOCAxMC43NjIsMTYgMi43NjksOC4wMDcgMi43NzYsOCIvPjwvc3ZnPg==");
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 10%;
height: 10%;
position: fixed;
top: 70%;
left: 0;
}
.test {
width: 10%;
height: 10%;
position: fixed;
top: 70%;
left: 0;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
-moz-background-clip: padding;
background-clip: padding-box;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
background-color: #000000;
background-color: transparent\9;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
text-indent: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and HTML here:

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="wrap">
     <h1>Stuff</h1>

    <div class="test"> 
        <a href="#" class="link">Hide me!</a>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="//placehold.it/150x150" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="//placehold.it/150x150" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="//placehold.it/150x150" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="//placehold.it/150x150" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="//placehold.it/150x150" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="//placehold.it/150x150" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="//placehold.it/150x150" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="//placehold.it/150x150" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="//placehold.it/150x150" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: You're right, your version works! I've also did some testing and noticed something strange: When you insert a PNG file as background image (at the moment it's SVG), then the problem is also fixed. Strange things going on there. Let's wait some more, but your post will be accepted I guess :-)

Comment: That some great progress, and with both these issues I have been able to track it down to a known bug in opera. It is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114636/opera-border-radius-svg-background-bug).